# How do I set Time.zone to UTC and keep it that way?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I have a Rails 3 application on Ruby 1.9.2 in which users enter business hours and they are stored in a MySQL database.  When a user does this, however, the entered time "8:00 AM" gets stored as 3pm in the database.  I want it to be stored as they entered it, regardless of time zone.  I figured the best way to do this is to set everything to UTC and have it ignore my time zone (Arizona), but Rails seems to be ignoring my setting.  Example:

```
Time.zone = 'UTC'

mon_open_date = Time.parse(params[:venue][:mon_open_at]) rescue nil

# => 2011-04-27 08:00:00 -0700
```

The result in MySQL:

```
+-------------+
| mon_open_at |
+-------------+
| 15:00:00    |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time.parse always parses the string into your computer's local timezone. You need to use `Time.zone.parse` in order to parse it as the specified timezone, UTC.

Answer (score 2):

**MySQL always [uses the server's time zone setting, by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)** (though you can change that, if you are the database admin).

If you store your date/time values in TIMESTAMP columns, **they are stored in a time-zone agnostic manner** (being converted to UTC for storage, and then back to the server's time zone again for usage).

If you store your date/times in a DATETIME column, **the values are stored exactly as you enter them** - if you change the server's time zone, and then SELECT old values out of a DATETIME column, you will see exactly the same values as when you entered them.

Check out the documentation on [DATETIME/TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) columns for the finer points.